# There is no document formatter for 'css'-files installed

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

When I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on CSS file in VSCode I get this error :

```
There is no document formatter for 'css'-files installed.
```

I installed extensions for css, but it is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739375/visual-studio-code-css-indentation-and-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut is usually
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

I don't know what extension you have installed, but here are some:

- [CSS Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter)
- [Beautify css/sass/scss/less](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier)
- [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)

Comment: alt+shift+f for windows ,,, ctrl+shift+i for linux ,,, and i install them .

Comment: It's strange that not one of these will work, unless something is wrong with vscode or the css file.